# Getting req.params.id undefined when making a put request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The problem is when I make the put request using postman there is an error in my vscode terminal that says:
let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

I am making this request on postman http://localhost:4500/api/v1/product/61dfc2ba3eb817d287929a7a
(61dfc2ba3eb817d287929a7a is the id) with body as raw json. req.params.id is coming to be undefined..

It seemed like an error in parsing so I added body-parser and cors to it but the same error is being showed up..

Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

mongoose
.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sampl", {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
 console.log("db connected");
})
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
description: String,
price: Number,
});

const Product = new mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
//create product
app.post("/api/v1/product/new", async (req, res) => {
const product = await Product.create(req.body);
console.log(req.body);
res.status(200).json({
 success: true,
 product,
});
});

//read product
app.get("/api/v1/products", async (req, res) => {
const products = await Product.find();
res.status(200).json({
 success: true,
 products,
});
});

//update product
app.put("/api/v1/product/:id", async (res, req) => {
let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
 new: true,
 useFindAndModify: false,
 runValidators: true,
});
res.status(200).json({
 success: true,
 product,
});
});

app.listen(4500, () => {
console.log("server is working");
});
```

Comment: Are you able to do a get or post request you had defined?

Comment: `(res, req)` - should be `(req, res)` !!!

Comment: Also, you dont need the "body-parser" - if you are using express v4.16.0 or greater, you can use the: `express.urlencoded()` and `express.json()`.

Comment: Okay, got it Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `req` object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, and HTTP headers. The `res` object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

So, first we want to pass the `req` object and then `res`.

change this

```
app.put("/api/v1/product/:id", async (res, req) => {
let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
```

to

```
app.put("/api/v1/product/:id", async (req, res) => {
let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
```